# understanding the 'this' keyword in Alloy

Tags: alloy

In the following code from section 4.7.2 of the Alloy book, what does the **this** keyword refer to?

```
module library/list [t]
sig List {}
sig NonEmptyList extends List {next: List, element: t}
```

...

```
fun List.first : t {this.element} 
fun List.rest : List {this.next} 
fun List.addFront (e: t): List {
    {p: List | p.next = this and p.element = e} 
}
```

I would appreciate if you give me an elaborate description of **this** usage in Alloy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 4.5.2 of *Software Abstractions* describes (among other things) what it calls the 'receiver' convention, that is the syntactic shorthand of writing functions and predicates as

```
fun X.f[y : Y, ...] { ... this ... }
```

instead of

```
fun f[x : X, y : Y, ...] { ... x ... }
```

That is, the declaration

```
fun List.first : t {this.element}
```

is equivalent to (and shorthand / syntactic sugar for)

```
fun first[x : List] : t {x.element}
```

And similarly for the other examples you give.  The parallel would be even stronger if we said the long form was

```
fun first[this : List] : t {this.element}
```

but while this is a useful illustration, it's not legal:  `this` is a keyword and cannot be used as an ordinary variable name.

---

You ask for an "elaborate description" of the usage of `this` in Alloy.  Here's a survey.  The keyword `this` can be used in the following situations:

- In declarations and signature facts, `this` acts as a variable implicitly bound to each instance of the signature.  So a declaration of the form

  ```
  sig Foo { ... } { copacetic[this] }
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  sig Foo { ... }
  fact { all f : Foo | copacetic[f] }
  ```
- In declarations and signature facts, every reference to a field `f` declared or inherited by the signature is implicitly expanded to `this.f`, where `this` is implicitly bound as described above, unless the reference is prefixed with `@`.  The example at the end of 4.2.4 illustrates the semantics.
- In the declaration bodies of functions and predicates declared using the 'receiver' convention, the keyword `this` acts as a variable implicitly bound to the first argument of the function or predicate.  The example at the end of 4.5.2 illustrates this, as does the example cited here by the OP.

  The 'receiver' convention is defined in section B.7.5 of the language reference.

All of these are pointed to from the entry for `this` in the index of *Software Abstractions*; for more information, read the relevant passages.